# JavaScript: How to open new window with default features?

Tags: javascript, parameters, default, window.open, new-window

The `window.open` function in JS can be used to open a new tab or window. By default, without the third param, it opens a new tab:

```
window.open("http://...","_blank");
```

When specifying the third param, it opens a new window:

```
window.open("http://...","_blank","location=yes,...");
```

However, I wish to let user open a **new window with default window features** just like when the user presses Ctrl+N or "New window" from menu. Possible?

Ps.
And it seems `window.open` can open a new browser window, but no tabs. However, I want tabs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is possibly 'no way' to window.open with tabs in new window.

However, if the JS code runs in browser extension, use extension API to create windows with tabs:

```
chrome.windows.create({url:SOME_URL});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use onkeydown captures keyboard events   and then open a new window

```
function document.onkeydown()   {
    if (event.ctrlKey == true && event.keyCode == 78) {//Ctrl+N 
        window.open("http://...","_blank","location=yes,...");
    }
}
```

also you can create Menu Button trigger the click event  open a new window

```
<script>

function doOpenWindow()   {
    window.open("http://...","_blank","location=yes,...");
}
```

```
<input type="button"  value="Menu" onClick="doOpenWindow()" />
```

Comment: uh no, i didn't mean to capture the ctrl+n event. I wanted to open a new window with default UI